# LinearOptimization and Accuracy

Tags: mathematical-optimization, precision-and-accuracy

Surprised to encounter the following issue in handling Accuracy with LinearOptimization:

```
LinearOptimization[x, 
                  {0``10 y + x == -1, y <= 1}, 
                  {x,  y}, 
                  {"PrimalMinimumValue", "PrimalMinimizerRules"}, 
                  WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

That raises two errors:

- **LinearOptimization::precw** signaling that 0``10 has precision less than the working precision.
- **LinearOptimization::lecbvec** complaining that {1 + 0``10. y} should be a vector of numeric values

The first error makes perfect sense. The second, lecbvec, error doesn't seem right.

```
NumericQ[0``10]
```

returns True as it should. So what isn't numeric to raise the lecbvec error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a workaround

```
LinearOptimization[x, Rationalize[{0``10 y + x == -1, y <= 1}, 0], {x,  y}, 
{"PrimalMinimumValue", "PrimalMinimizerRules"},  WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with Rationalize. Passing through CoefficientArrays or, less satisfactory, appending /.x_?NumberQ:>Chop[x] to transform 0``10 to 0, work as well, but Rationalize is better than both. I think this is a bug in that LinearOptimization is parsing 0``10 y incorrectly. No?